# Vuejs toggle div visibility on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

I am trying to toggle the visibility of a container div using Vuejs I have tried two methods as per below but neither have any affect on visibility of the container. Method 1:

```
<body>
    <div class="checkbox" id = "selector">
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">Options</label>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="checked">
        <p>Text is visible</p>
    </div>
<script src="path_to_/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#selector',
        data: {
            "checked": false
        }
     })
</script>
</body>
```

I know Vue.js loads OK, ticking the checkbox has no effect on text visibility.

Method 2:

```
<body>
    <div class="checkbox" id = "selector">
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-on:click="seen = !seen">Options</label>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="seen">
        <p>Text is visible</p>
    </div>
<script src="path_to_/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#selector',
        data: {
            "seen": false
        }
     })
</script>
</body>
```

Again, ticking the checkbox has no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to wrap `checkbox` element  within `div` element with `selector` id attribute.

The `vue` element which you're creating it is only available for the div which contains the `checkbox`.

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#selector',
        data: {
            checked: false
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>
   <div id="selector">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">Options</label>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="checked">
        <p>Text is visible</p>
    </div>       
   </div>
</body>
```