# Switch divs by clicking on checkbox (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an authentication page, and I have a checkbox. My main idea is to switch forms, my checkbox says 'Already have an account' if it's clicked I wanna show Sign Up form, if it's unchecked I wanna show sign in form.

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314118/vuejs-toggle-div-visibility-on-checkbox-selection) example and that's what I got inside my  tag:

```
<div id='#selector'>
<div class="container">
  <label class="bs-switch">
    Already have an account
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
  <div class="row" v-if="checked">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I didn't copy the whole form, it's just a default bootstrap sign in page.

And inside my  tag:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#selector',
  data: {
    checked: false
  }
});
```

It does show the checkbox, but it's not showing my Sign In card. The error:

> Property or method "checked" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

and

> "export 'default' (imported as '**vue_script**') was not found in '!!babel-loader!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Auth.vue'

What am I missing?

Comment: Might not be relevant but you have wrong id. In HTML you have "#selector" where you probably intended only "selector".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've managed to fix it myself. I didn't have to import Vue or create a new vue element. I just used data function:

```
export default {


data: function() {
    return {
      checked: false
    }
  }
}
```